# website facebook like button facebook business page merge

Tags: html, facebook

I am trying to merge my website and facebook business page together. I built the website before I really knew how to use it and I integrated the like button before I built a facebook business page now I have more likes on my website then my business page does anyone know how to make them the same?

Comment: Your Facebook page an object and Your website is another graph object! they have different IDs, You can't merge them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you can only do this from the beginning :(

There are two different types of likes...

1) 'like's for a website, article, post etc which when someone clicks like it posts on their wall - friends and family see the like but then it disappears into obscurity. You are able to have no further interaction with that person.

2) 'like' for a facebook page which is kept, forever linking your page to that person and posts in the page show on that persons news feed. It also shows as a recommendation to friends visiting that page 'so and so likes this page' etc.

I'm afraid **you can't transfer likes for your website to likes for your facebook page**. But I'd certainly suggest you switch the like code on your website to a like box, containing the page like button. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/

Now when visitors see your site, they not only see how many people like your company, but if they also click like, that like is counted for the facebook page too.

Its a very good idea for new companies to set themselves up with a like **box** and not a like **button** right from the get go. I'm sorry that you'll 'lose' those likes from your website, but you can't market to those people, whereas you can to your page likers. It sounds like you're already successfully gathering a following so don't be too disheartened!

Comment: Thank You, appreciate the descriptive answer I will just change it you were my final decision!